# URLs with special symbols don't seem to work with TeXShop

Tags: hyperref, urls, texshop

I've been using TeXShop for ages, it is my to-go LaTeX editor.

When compiling (LaTeX) URLs with special symbols get screwed up hyperlinks, no matter what I try. Not even definining the url outside the document such as in the following MWE where the % symbol produces a %25 in the hyperlink

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\urldef{\myurl}\url{https://www.cmu.edu/news/stories/archives/2018/january/images/MATH-18-114_Math%20Newsletter_Gerrymandering.pdf}

\begin{document}

\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu\relax    
\myurl

\end{document}
```

I tried the commands \detokenize, \string, \noexpand to no avail. It seems strictly related to the TeXShop editor. I tried the TeXworks that comes with the latest MiKTeX console and it produces the right output. Same goes compiling on the arXiv repository.

How do I get TeXShop to do it properly (I have the latest version, 4.44)?

Edit: The problem appears when

a) I open the pdf with the MacOS preview application (which seems to be faulty and unable to handle hyperlinks)

b) I compile the source and view the pdf with TeXShop's built-in previewer.

It does not appear with TeXworks' built-in previewer.

Edit: attached below a screenshot of the MWE of TeXShop's built-in previewer where the hyperlink is not correct.

[image]

Comment: The example works perfectly fine for me and links to a live document. Can you show a screenshot of how it doesn't work in TeXShop? If the problems turns out to be that TeXShop's viewer has an issue with this, then this should probably be reported to the developers. Can you open the PDF produced by the TeXShop run and independently check with a different PDF viewer if the link is OK or not?

Comment: It does not work in TeXShop, that is what disturbes me.

Comment: Urgh, sorry confused TeXshop and Texstudio. Will edit the comment shortly. But the request still stands.

Comment: if "not work" means that the link doesn't work in the pdf-preview: apple pdf viewer seem to have problems with such links. Not much you can do apart complaining to apple.

Comment: Good to know, I got a collegue of mine to open it and it does work. It seems that it is the Apple pdf-preview to screw up things. This was not happening with TeXworks because it was using some other built-in method of preview.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you've raised on a MacOS 10.15.4, MacTeX2020 (with all updates applied), and TeXshop 4.44, and TeXshop's built-in pdf previewer.

Comment: @GiorgioSaracco: I have no problem with the link in the Preview window in TeXShop? What version of macOS, TeXShop and TeX Distribution are you using?

Comment: @Herb Schulz. I have issues both with apple pdf-preview and TeXShop's built-in previewer. I'm on TeXShop 4.44, MiKteK 2.9.7414. The only non-latest release I have is the MacOS which is Catalina 10.15 (sooner or later I will update to 10.15.4).

Comment: Now, this is weird. Checking the TeXShop's log it seems that it loads TeX Live 2017. I suppose at some point I changed distribution but folders were not put in the right place, damn myself.

Comment: I tried changing the path to the MiKTeK distribution; TeXShop's built-in previewer still fails linking the right url. I updated TeXLive to 2020 and used it as distribution; TeXShop's built-in previewer still fails linking the right url. I'll try updating Catalina and see what happens.

Comment: Did you install MikTeX for personal use (~/bin for binaries) or system-wide use (/usr/local/bin for binaries)? I hope for former and not the latter. Is there a reason you didn't install MacTeX-2020 which installs TeX Live 2020?

Comment: I installed MikTeX for personal use (~/bin). Then, I installed MacTeX-2020 to try with TeX Live 2020 and changed back the engine path (/Library/TeX/texbin) but still fails producing the correct hyperlink in the built-in previewer.